# CSS help - Shopify Blockshop theme collection page alt image hover changes

Tags: css, mouseover, shopify

**EDITED** 
Maddy - thank you SO much, the below worked perfectly for issues 1 and 3, great to have learned how to do this. 
Regarding #2 - editing in my original below.

///ORIGINAL STARTS HERE///

Need to fix the following on the collection pages for this site, here's an example of one of the collection pages:
http://www.sachinandbabi.com/collections/tops

1. Remove the opacity on hover
2. For thumbs that are 267px wide, the alt image on mouseover is showing up offset. Example: Keanu Top.
   Need to fix this. **EDIT: ADDING SCREEN SHOT LINK TO SHOW WHAT IS HAPPENING - FOR THUMBS THAT ARE 267 PX WIDE, THE HOVER IMAGE IS SHOWING UP 43PX TO THE LEFT OF THE ORIGINAL THUMB, IT SHOULD APPEAR, ON MOUSEOVER, DIRECTLY OVER THE ORIGINAL IMAGE AS TO CONCEAL THE ORIGINAL IMAGE.**

LINK:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxyx2FFWzBJjRGhCVVlBR1dadWs/view?usp=sharing

3. "SALE" and "SOLD OUT" circle needs to appear to stay on mouseover

I've tried to fix this myself but have hit a wall. If anyone is able to help, and I need to give more info, please let me know so I can send it over.

Below are the module from my style.css.liquid and the image wrapper. Thanks all.

```css
/* ===============================================
// 4.10 Reveal module
// =============================================== */
 
.reveal .hidden { display: block !important; visibility: visible !important;}
.product:hover .reveal img { opacity: 1; }
.reveal { position: relative; }
.reveal .hidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0; 
  width: auto; 
  height: 100%;  
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.reveal:hover .hidden { 
  z-index: 100000;
  opacity: 1;    
}
.reveal .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;  
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white; /* fallback for IE8 */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font: 13px/1.6 sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.reveal .hidden .caption .centered {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
 
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .reveal .caption { 
    font-size: 11px; 
  }
}




/*Here's the image wrapper from snippet-product-item.liquid*/

  <div class="product-item {{ column-classes }}">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
          {% if product.available == false %}
        <div class="circle sold-out">Sold<br />Out</div>
      {% elsif product.compare_at_price > product.price %}  
        <a class="circle sale" href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">Sale</a>
      {% endif %}   
      {% assign ratio = settings.product_img_w_to_h_ratio | times: 1.0 %}
      <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
        {% if snippet-product-item == '3' or ratio < 1 %}
       <div class="reveal">
        <img {% if product_slider %}class="lazyOwl" data-src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'large' }}"{% endif%} src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
        {% else %}
        <img {% if product_slider %}class="lazyOwl" data-src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' }}"{% endif%} src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
        {% endif %}
        {% if snippet-product-item == '3' or ratio < 1 %}
         <img class = "hidden" {% if product_slider %}class="lazyOwl" data-src="{{ product.images[2] | product_img_url: 'large' }}"{% endif%} src="{{ product.images[2] | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.images[2]alt | escape }}" />
        {% else %}
        <img class = "hidden" {% if product_slider %}class="lazyOwl" data-src="{{ product.images[2] | product_img_url: 'medium' }}"{% endif%} src="{{ product.images[2] | product_img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ product.images[2]alt | escape }}" />
        {% endif %}      
        </div>  
       </a>
    </div><!-- .coll-image-wrap -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some change in your css:-

**For opacity:-**

```
 .product-grid .image-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 100%;
        opacity: 1 !important; // add this in your css
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

**For "SALE" and "SOLD OUT" circle -**

```
.reveal {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; // add this in your css
}

.product-grid .circle {
    font-size: 1.16667em;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 35px 0 0;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 90px;
    z-index: 2; // add this in your css
}
```

**Image hover changes :-**

```
.reveal .hidden {
    height: 100%;
    left: 10px;  // Change this in your css
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: auto;
    z-index: -1; }
```

Comment: Hi Maddy - Again I can't thank you enough for your help. See edited comment for clarification on second point.

Comment: Hi Maddy! This still isn't working on supersize. Is there any way to tell the original thumbnail to "hide" on hover so white bg color only appears behind the hover image? If not, I'm going to have to come up with some other solutions. The problem is really only happening when the browser is supersized (on a large monitor). All other sizes are working now. I ended up increasing the height and width 5% and lowering the image caption. Which works for all the other browser sizes, except supersize is still causing the issue.

Comment: Hi Again! I think I can figure this out myself now, after the little bit you shared with me and some more research on my own. Thanks!!!!